# how to execute query for each row result of another query

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables , one stores IDs and another logs for each ID , i would like to get sum of log for each ID and ID number from these 2 tables

```
   A               B
-------        -------------
ID             ID_C     LOG
1               1        15
2               1        30
3               4        44
4               2        14
5               3        88
                3        10
                2        10
```

for getting sum query is

```
SELECT SUM(LOG) FROM B WHERE ID_C ='2' ;
```

- notice ID and ID_C are same but name is different in tables
  and for getting all ids available  query is

  SELECT ID FROM A  ;

I would  like to get the following table result

```
      result
--------------------
ID         SUM
1          45
4          44
2          24
3          98
```

I tried

```
SELECT SUM(LOG) FROM B WHERE ID_C in (SELECT ID FROM A ) ;
```

but it result in sum of all IDs

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Remove the unrelated tag.)

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just need a join aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT a.ID, SUM(b.LOG) AS SUM
FROM A a
INNER JOIN B b
    ON b.ID_C = a.ID
GROUP BY a.ID
ORDER BY a.ID;
```

Note that the inner join will also remove `ID` values from the `A` table which no entries whatsoever in the `B` table, which seems to be the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

you should use inner join and  GROUP BY:

```
SELECT A.ID as ID, SUM(LOG) AS SumLOG
FROM A inner join B ON A.ID = B.ID_C
GROUP BY A.ID
```

if you needed can use where for ID filter.